# Start page for namespaces in MediaWiki

Tags: namespaces, mediawiki

I am trying to get my head around using namespaces in MediaWiki. I'm not sure my idea is even possible in MediaWiki. Hope someone can help me out.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: I've got a running instance of MediaWiki and some custom namespaces declared (let's call them Test1 and Test2). In each namespace you have several articles (pages) and subarticels (subpages). This works well.

Now I'd like to have a start page for each namespace that lists all the articles of that namespace. I know there is a Special:`AllPages-Thing`, that can list all pages for a namespace, but I'd rather have it included in a page under the given namespace (like a list of subpages).

It would be ideal to have it under `wiki.xyz/index.php/Test1:`, but this does not seem possible.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your index page and in it add code like `{{Special:Allpages|namespace=123}}`. This will include a list of all pages in the namespace number `123` into the current page.

Comment: Special:Allpages instead of Spacial:Allpages worked